# Avoid Hardcoding Of UserId's in Apex

Tags: bestpractice

In one of the triggers, they have hard coded the userid, as below. How can we avoid this?

```
       if(currentUser != '012300000012345PPPP' && Utils.isS == false)
       {
             //DO SOMETHING
       }
```

Comment: What is special about that user that you do not want this to work for them? If there is something special that you could use, like a new role, or a custom checkbox on the user screen, that could help give a better way of flagging them. Then, you shouldn't have to modify your code whenever a change is made. You would only need to make the user match the code's criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not want the user id to be hardcoded as a string in Apex code then you should create a custom setting and then you can query the value in the trigger.

```
  Settings__c settings = Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
  if (UserInfo.getUserId() != settings.SpecialUser) {
     //do logic for all users except the special user
  }
  else
  {
     //special user logic
  }
```

When the special user changes you can update the user id on the custom setting.  Without modifying source code.

You could also use a Custom Permission and Permission Set to control access to a section of code. Create a Custom Permission 'Special User' assign to a permission set 'Special User Rights'.

```
  CustomPermission custPerm = [select id from CustomPermission where developerName = 'Special User' limit 1];

  List<SetupEntityAccess> access = [select setupEntityType, setupEntityId, parentId from SetupEntityAccess where setupEntityId = :custPerm.Id and ParentId IN (SELECT PermissionSetId from PermissionSetAssignment where AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId())];

  if (access.size() > 0) {
     //execute special user logic
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just did this and it works fine. I appreciate you help

Answer (score 2):

Another option that avoids the custom setting would be to create a role, put the single user in the role, and then query membership of the role using the DeveloperName of the role.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: This would be applicable if the requirement were 'if user in Role X then execute logic X otherwise execute logic for all other roles'

Comment: @DeveloperWonk With that in mind this would probably work better as a permission set.

Comment: @Namfuak updated original answer with alternative using custom permission and permission set